# My custom operator needs a precedence group?

Tags: swift

So I have a custom operator `≈` that works fine when comparing one pair of numbers but fails when I try to compare more than one pair. The code snippet below can be thrown right into a playground to replicate the error.

```
infix operator ≈

 func ≈ (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool {
      lhs < rhs + 80 && lhs > rhs - 80
 }

 let results = 100 ≈ 75 && 89 ≈ 78 //<-- `Adjacent operators are in unordered precedence groups 'DefaultPrecedence' and 'LogicalConjunctionPrecedence'`
```

I read the docs on it but did not receive much understanding on how to fix this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to group your operands:

```
let results = (100 ≈ 75) && (89 ≈ 78)
```

Or define your new operator precedence:

```
precedencegroup CongruentPrecedence {
    lowerThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
    associativity: left
}

infix operator ≈:CongruentPrecedence
```

Comment: The irony here is I've never used Swift, I just googled for the error